# Opening new window and allowing & sign/ numbers

Tags: jquery

Goal: when users type in anything in an input box, it will open a new window and append &yuri=0 to it.


Current code:

```
    $(function() {
    $('.baseUrl').click( function() {
    window.location = $(this).attr('href')  +  $('.appendUrl').val() + '&yuri=0'; 

    return false;


   });
   });
```

The HTML:

```
 <input type="text" class="appendUrl" /><br>
 <a href="http://" class="baseUrl">Click Here</a>
```

Right now it opens in the same window, and the & and =0 are not showing up properly.
Any insight would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a new window try the [`window.open()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open) instead of setting the `window.location`:

```
$(function() {
    $('.baseUrl').click(function() {
        window.open($(this).attr('href') + $('.appendUrl').val() + '?yuri=0', 'newwinnamehere');

        return false;    
    });
});​
```

(Really simplified) Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qzfsK/1

Note also that the bit you want to append on the end should start with a `?` not a `&` - unless the user has already entered a `?` - so really you should have an `if` test to check for that:

```
var url = $('.appendUrl').val();
window.open($(this).attr('href') + url + (url.indexOf('?') != -1 ? '&' : '?') + 'yuri=0', "newwinname");
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick answer. I am still wondering, could I replace the ? with the &. When I try it on my end, it fails. With the question mark it works fine, but I need the & sign at the intro. Is there a way to do the if to check for the ? mark and replace it with & sign? Thanks once again! :) cheers.

Comment: Why do you need the `&`? Standard URL query-string format uses a `?` to separate the parameters from the address, and then `&` between individual parameters (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string), and as you've already seen it doesn't work with just an `&`.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for the info. Unfortunately, the parameter won't work without the & in this case. I will look into more resources on how to solve this, or maybe have the & by default in the text box. Cheers and appreciate all the info! -Y

Comment: If you're saying you need the ampersand as part of the actual _data_ then you need to replace it with `%26`. (Google "url encoding" for more info.)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following instead:

```
window.open(URL);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to be working fine in jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/gcskm/

It looks like the error you're running in to is with the "&". & is only for values added to the URL after the first. For the first you want "?". So you would need to detect if there is already at least one variable. If so use "&" otherwise use "?".